# Grails can't load maven-publisher

Tags: grails, maven-2, maven-plugin, grails-2.3

I am trying to add `maven-publisher` to a Grails (2.3.6) plugin like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.107'
    compile ":maven-publisher:0.8.1"
}
```

When I run `grails compile` I get:

```
| Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates
:maven-publisher:0.8.1, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[
:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `compile ":maven-publisher:0.8.1"` being a Grails plugin should be under `plugins { }` instead of `dependencies { }`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `maven-publisher` plugin. It's old and deprecated. Use the `release` plugin - it should already be in your plugin's `BuildConfig.groovy`. If not, here's how it should look (after removing unnecessary cruft):

```
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

   inherits 'global'
   log 'warn'

   repositories {
      grailsCentral()
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      compile 'org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:0.107'
   }

   plugins {
      build ':release:3.0.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', {
         export = false
      }
   }
}
```

As @dmahapatro said in his comment, jar dependencies go in the `dependencies` block, and plugin dependencies go in the `plugins` block.

Note also that you should keep the `export = false` setting so the plugin is available locally for your use, but doesn't leak into the containing application as an unnecessary transitive dependency.